# OCR output save to one text file automatically to folder

Tags: python, text, directory, ocr

I am doing OCR on image.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
img1=Image.open('my.png')
print(image_to_string(img1))
```

How can save the extracted information into text file called "Output.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the easy way to save OCR output into text file

```
def ocr(file_to_ocr):
    im = Image.open(file_to_ocr)
    txt=pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
    return txt

directory = os.path.join("Your_path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
for file in files:
   if file.endswith(".jpg"):
      pre_fix=file[:-4]
      txt=ocr(file)
      with open(directory+"\\"+pre_fix+".txt",'w') as f: f.write(str(txt))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a unique folder name using `uuid`, and then write the output.txt to it like so?:

```
from uuid import uuid4
import os

folder_name = str(uuid4())
os.makedirs(folder_name)
with open('./{fn}/output.txt'.format(fn=folder_name),'wb') as f:
    f.write(image_to_string(img1))
```